# Can I get maven to require a particular version of itself, or better yet to resolve such a version?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

Sorry if this has been asked before, but "maven" and "version" are difficult terms to pair with each other.

I'd like it if I could depend on maven version 3.0.4 and everyone's maven simply update itself. Worse (but still usable) would be to simply require that everyone have a recent enough version of maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pom add

<prerequisites>
    <maven>3.0.4</maven>
  </prerequisites>

Or enforcer plugin: see http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html

Answer (score 1):

Thats what the maven-enforcer-plugin is supposed to do. That has a [suitable standard rule](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html) for you. However I don't think that it  is possible to switch to another maven version in a maven build. That also might cause more confusion than it solves problems.